Placing MOSFET heatsink on PCB?
I'm printing a PCB for the first time, and I would like to know the best way to heatsink the MOSFETs; I'm using 4 RFD16N06LESM9A surface mount MOSFETS connected in parallel:


Would it be best to mount the heatsink on the other side of the PCB (directly below the FETs)? Or maybe mount it across the top surface of them? Or something else?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. :D

How much power are you dissipating?

@TimWilliams the maximum is 2.25W per MOSFET (so 9W total)

Please use individual gate resistors for each MOSFET. Ask me how I know.

@winny Ok I'll bite... how do you know??

Product I developed had two parallel TO-220 MOSFETs. Passed all type tests and pre-production units at select customers without any issues. Fast forward a few months and the warehouse had pallets worth of customer returns, all with the same error - blown MOSFET pair. Turns out, initial run was lucky when it came to Vgsth spread. Once initial spool ran out during mass production, there would be an oscillation between them. The lowest Vgsth one would turn on first, Miller capacitance would turn it off and then a final blow to SOAR, shorting it. With separate gate resistors there were no issues.

What exactly are you designing?

Given recent history, it seems likely this is a linear application. I would suggest answerers to include comments regarding the parallel connection of FETs in active mode.

In active (linear) mode, Vgsth tempco is negative, so the hottest FET gets more current and you get thermal run away and smoke. So you either need a FET with higher dissipation (thru hole) or source resistors to help share current. In switching mode, it's the opposite, RdsON increases with temperature so the hottest FET gets less current which helps sharing current equally. So you need to say which use case you're considering.

When paralleling FETs, you need to make sure that they share heat equally.  Otherwise you run into current hogging between them and defeating the purpose of paralleling.
If you do this with SMT, use lots of copper and put them close together.  You can put them on opposite sides of the PCB and add via in pads with like 6+ vias between them.  It's similar to using TO220 and putting them on opposite sides of a heatsink from each other.
Also, each gate needs its own resistor to decouple the variations in gate capacitance from each other.
And if the power/current is high, then adding a source resistor will also help to balance the FETs.  The resistor can be picked using this equation as a guide:
\$\Delta Vgs_{th}=I_d*R_s\$ where \$\Delta Vgs_{th}\$ is the max-min from the datasheet.
See Nexperia App Note AN11599
TI put together a decent app note on this topic: Tips for Successfully Paralleling Power MOSFETs.  Here are some highlights:

Each FET needs its own gate resistor with a value
from a few ohms up to tens of ohms. This helps
with current sharing and prevents gate oscillations.
FETs need good thermal coupling to ensure
current and thermal balancing between devices.
They can be mounted on a common heat sink or
copper plane to maintain equal temperatures.
The placement and layout of each FET should
be identical and symmetrical, within reason, to
equalize parasitic inductance in the critical gate-tosource and drain-to-source loops.
Ensure that the gate-drive circuit can drive the
higher capacitance (charge) of multiple devices
without getting too hot. Remember, capacitance
(charge) is multiplied by the number of paralleled
MOSFETs.
Avoid adding external capacitors from gate-tosource or gate-to-drain. If necessary, adjust the
gate resistor’s value to optimize the switching
speed of the FETs .
If you need Zener diodes to protect the MOSFET
driver, place them close to the gate-driver outputs
and before the gate resistors.


Opposite side of PCB will be limited by the via thermal resistance. You can use for example Saturn PCB calculator to estimate the resistance. It will take a lot of them. Check the via rules for your PCB manufacturer on how close, how many and what size. Since this is usually free, you see this in a lot of designs but the thermal resistance is high compared to cooling on the same side of the PCB.
Your other options is to have a soldered SMD heatsink on the same side, like this:

Image from Why are these SMD heatsinks designed to not touch the IC?
Also, consider if it’s cheaper to skip the heatsink + mounting cost all together by buying better MOSFETs in the first place.

I'd probably consider using a standing TO220 part instead, if you are going to mess around with manually mounted heat sinks anyway. Because such parts have better cooling and doesn't heat up the PCB needlessly.

@Lundin I like this idea, how would you suggest I connect the heatsink to the standing part? Just stick it on with thermal paste?

@Dip Thermal paste or similar wouldn't hurt, but generally it is attached with rivets or screws etc. TO220 come with a hole in the IC heatsink for this very purpose - these are standard products, just search for "to220 heatsink".

It requires a significant amount of 2 oz Cu area to transfer the heat to an acceptable temperature.  If your spec approaches any of the SOA limits you will need thru-hole devices with large surface area heatsinks.  Convection air must not be restricted and perhaps set in a vertical orientation.  Now this must be scaled up with 4 devices.

I do not think this is a feasible approach for a printed PCB to save on DPAK area and lose on 2 oz Cu cost area if this demands more than a typical CPU power in total.  Unless you have a budget for power, conservative Tj max and cost, glass-transition temp, this does not seem like the best approach for a powerful H-bridge until you prove me wrong.
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00004438-953624.pdf
